# Spring + React fetch data

Tags: json, spring, reactjs, api

i have a problem with fetch data from api exposed by spring. 
I want to fetch data by:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.setState({isLoading: true});

fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/tasks/')
.then(response => { return response.json() })
.then(results => this.setState({
  tasks: results,
  isLoading: false
}));
```

The spring api which return data:

```
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:3000")
  @GetMapping
  public List<Task> findTasksByUserId() {
    return taskService.findTasksBelongToUser(idProvider.getCurrentUserId());
  }
```

Returned JSON:

```
[
{
id: 1,
version: 0,
name: "Task1",
description: "description1",
priority: 1,
finished: true,
category: {
id: 1,
version: 0,
name: "Uncategorized",
user: {
id: 1,
version: 0,
login: "admin",
email: "admin@todo.pl",
enabled: true
}
},
user: {
id: 1,
version: 0,
login: "admin",
email: "admin@todo.pl",
enabled: true
},
position: 0
},
{
id: 2,
version: 0,
name: "Task2",
description: "description2",
priority: 4,
finished: true,
category: {
id: 1,
version: 0,
name: "Uncategorized",
user: {
id: 1,
version: 0,
login: "admin",
email: "admin@todo.pl",
enabled: true
}
},
user: {
id: 1,
version: 0,
login: "admin",
email: "admin@todo.pl",
enabled: true
},
position: 1
}]
```

And i got a error like this:

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I dont know what is wrong but maybe format of json is not correct, because it's start with the sign '['.
I am a beginner in React so please about some hint and help.
regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch()` returns a promise which gets resolved into an HTTP response of course, not the actual JSON. To extract the JSON body content from the response, we use the `json()` method.

Try adding two headers `Content-Type` and `Accept` to be equal to `application/json`.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/tasks/', {
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
       }

    })
.then(response => { return response.json() })
.then(results => this.setState({
  tasks: results,
  isLoading: false
}));
```

Comment: Ok, but now i have a problem with function map in this line {tasks.map(task => (
                <li key={task.id}>
                  {task.name}
                </li>
            ))}

Comment: what problem? If the `tasks` is an array `map` should work

Comment: hmm that's weird because like i show above json is an array with objects

Comment: If its array of objects then the function passed as argument to map will be executed for all objects in the array. Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: No i am not yet, i dont't know why map doesnt fit

Comment: yes i got error like this Uncaught TypeError: tasks.map is not a function

Comment: Check what type "tasks" is being set to, and make sure that it is an array.

Comment: when i did console.log(tasks) i got something like this Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:8080/login", redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Comment: i don't know why it redirect to /login

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183656/discussion-between-shivam-and-adrian).